# HP Laserjet paper jam

Tags: hp-laserjet, paper-tray

I have a LaserJet 2300d that gets jammed about 1 in every 10 pages printed (duplex mode). I suspect it's picking up two pages by mistake because when I open it up there's always two pages jammed in different places.

Are there any DIY fixes for this?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked the rollers? After a lot of use the rollers lose their grip and become almost 'glassy' in feel. This causes a lot of paper misfeeds.
Fortunately they are very cheap to replace.
I've often wondered about 'roughing' them up again, perhaps with sandpaper. I've never tried this so on your head be it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the rollers are getting glassy, and you cannot get replacement rollers (too old? not available in your country?), there is one trick that one could use from my old technician days. Acetone (usually found as nail polish remover) is useful for removing the glassy residue on the rollers and restoring them to a softer texture. One should be extremely careful and remove the rollers from the printer before doing this as acetone will aggressively dissolve plastics and ruin the rest of your printer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes changing the type of paper (weight, etc) solves it. Even just a different brand. But it can surely be what Joe Taylor mentioned. When using heavy paper though, and/or duplex mode, there are some more chances for it to happen, in my experience.